Performance improvement for SQL for a specific case
I have 2 tables like below:
A



AId,
BId
Date1
Date2




1
B1
1 Jan 2021
31 Dec 2021


1
B1
1 Jan 2022
31 Dec 2022


1
B1
1 Jan 2023
31 Dec 2030


2
B2
1 Jan 2021
31 Dec 2030


3
B3
1 Jan 2024
31 Dec 2030



B



BId
BVal




B1
B1


B2
B2


B3
B3



I am joining these two tables A and B based on BId column. One input of Date type is coming in the query and we want to filter the data from table A based on that parameter and need the output of below data.
Input passed to the query (input_date): 1 Jan 2022



AId
BId
Date1
Date2




1
B1
1 Jan 2022
31 Dec 2022 (There are multiple records of this but it should only come once)


2
B2
1 Jan 2021
31 Dec 2030


3
B3
1 Jan 2024
31 Dec 2030 (This is starting in future still it should come in output)



I am using below query currently but its pulling duplicate records.
select AId, BId, Date1, Date2
from A,B
where A.BId = B.BId
and input_date <= A.Date2; -- We cant add check of Date1 as we want the record with AId '3' from table A.

But this is pulling all rows from A for the record with id '1'. We just want 1 row as mentioned.
One option I can think of is to add distinct or group by but wanted to check if there is any better alternate to achieve this requirement. I am thinking DISTINCT or GROUP BY would have a performance impact as the number of rows increase.
Can this be handled in a better way?
PS: These are just sample tables Actual tables are bigger with large data.
Edit:
Condition is Inputdate<= date2.
Datebase: Oracle

I think, something wrong with date. Pls, show table A and table B definition (structure).

The A,B join syntax has been obsolete for more than 30 years now. Time to learn to do it right.

Oh: and what kind of database is this? Since most databases don't follow the ansi standard very closely for date functions, it's going to matters for this query.

Condition is input_date <= date2. Corrected in the question. I am using Oracle db

The question is unclear because the input date in 2022 is not greater than the Date2 values in 2030, even though the code sample says it should be both rows 2 and 3, but only row 3 mentions an exception. It also fails to tell us what kind of database to use, because date functions are different between different types of database.
This is written assuming SQL Server's date functions. If you're using a different database, the date functions will be different, and you should have told us what you had.
It uses the row_number() windowing function to rank rows, and then filter for only the top-ranked row in each group. This allows you to still include a row that might not match the main criteria (based on the "starting the future but should still come in output" remark), but numbered in such a way that these rows will always give way to rows in the partition that DO match the criteria. Because the question is not clear, the ranking as written is almost certainly wrong, but it should point you toward a solution that can work.
with numbered as (
    select A.AId, b.BId, Date1, Date2
       , row_number() over (partition by A.AId, B.BId
                                     -- prefer dates that meet the criteria
                            order by case when @input_date >= A.Date2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
                                     -- and then find the value nearest the requested date
                                     abs(datediff(day, @input_date, A.Date2)) ) rn                 
    from A
    inner join B ON A.BId = B.BId
)
select AID, BId, Date1, Date2
from numbered
where rn = 1

There might also be a solution based on conditional aggregation (group by plus a case expression inside an aggregate function) that could perform better, but without a clearer question I don't want to attempt it.

Sorry. The condition was incorrect. Condition is input_date <= date2. I am using Oracle DB
